# Add root folder in git commit

Tags: git

I want to commit the root folder to stash. 
But this root folder doesn't cotain the .git folder
Below is the folder structure..Please suggest

ProjectA--> src(.git folder in this folder)-->main

when I am commiting the project...the folder in src(main)is being committed.
instead we want to commit src folder.

Please help

Comment: You cannot commit something that is outside of the repository. In case you have just started this project it would perhaps be easier to start over with a clean repository in the right directory. Remove the `.git` directory in `src` and create a new one (`git init`) in the `ProjectA` directory. It is possible move `.git` including any history in the current repository, but you will want to shift the directory structure in it, which is possible but not trivial.

Comment: @jsageryd is correct. In your project, your git repo is *inside* the **src** directory. You would need to reinitialise a new git repository in the **ProjectA** folder to do what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @shree have you seen the comments?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes..got a workaround for that..thanks :)

Comment: Ok. If you feel this question is no longer relevant, please close it. Or add an answer so that it may help others.